# Is there a word that describes taking some clothes with both hands raising your arms and quickly bringing them down?

Tags: meaning

I'm not talking about only using 1 hand, but both, as when you're done laundering clothes.

Comment: The best I can think of is *to shake out*, e.g.,   "Grasp the shirt with both hands at the top of each shoulder, shake out and lay flat."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think my mom used to call that *snapping* the clothes.

One definition from http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/snap

> > *snap*: to move with a quick, short movement or to cause (something) to move with a quick, short movement
> >
> > ◾Flags snapped in the wind.